# Topic Remapping at Runtime

Tags: ros2, topics, remap, remapping

Is it possible to remap the name of a topic at runtime?

To formulate the question more clearly, I need to remap the subscription of a node. I know that it can be done from `ros2 run` and from a launch file, but I was wondering if I could change the subscription at run time from the command line.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it is the most elegant way, but it is possible to achieve this as follows:

You could put the topic name in a parameter, and add a 'post set' parameter callback that resets the current subscriber and creates a new one for the changed topic name.

See the [set_parameters_callback demo](https://github.com/ros2/demos/blob/647f858a80cefa5bf205b0b48c255b28dd18a7a1/demo_nodes_cpp/src/parameters/set_parameters_callback.cpp#L105-L106) for example code wrt. defining the callback, i.e. something similar to this:

```cpp
auto post_set_parameter_callback =
  [this](const std::vector<rclcpp::Parameter> & parameters) {
    for (const auto & param : parameters) {
      if (param.get_name() == "topic_name") {
        std::string new_topic = this->get_parameter("topic_name").as_string();
        // Delete current subscriber
        // Create new subscriber
      }
    }
  }

post_set_parameters_callback_handle_ = this->add_post_set_parameters_callback(post_set_parameter_callback);
```

EDIT:

I coincidentally found following issue: [Dynamically remap topic names](https://github.com/ros2/rcl/issues/1072) that discusses this.
So it is indeed not implemented yet.

EDIT 2:

See also this issue: [Topic still registered after publisher has been destroyed](https://github.com/ros2/rclcpp/issues/2146) with following [workaround](https://github.com/ros2/rclcpp/issues/2146#issuecomment-1507474907).

Comment: That is interesting! I will try it in the future if I happen to bump in the same situation again.

Answer (score 0):

> "if I could change the subscription at run time from the command line

You can remap the subscribed topic from the command line using `--ros-args --remap`. Example:

`ros2 run demo_nodes_cpp listener --ros-args --remap /chatter:=/alt_chatter`

And, in another window at the same time, this remaps the published topic:

`ros2 run demo_nodes_cpp talker --ros-args --remap /chatter:=/alt_chatter`

After which you should see this in the first window:

```
[INFO] [1699004739.415840016] [listener]: I heard: [Hello World: 1]
[INFO] [1699004740.415364437] [listener]: I heard: [Hello World: 2]
[INFO] [1699004741.415355329] [listener]: I heard: [Hello World: 3]
```

Comment: Not exactly what I wanted to do. 
My intention was to change the subscription after I launched the node, i.e. node is subscribing to "Topic 1" and after a command is subscribed to "Topic 2". It was more of an hack to avoid to write a more structured code to debug the application I was working on.

In the end I ended up writing down the more structured solution with launch files.